# Array fills with only last element

Tags: java, arrays, object, shallow-copy

I'm trying to solve an [8-puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle), and I'm trying to generate possible board configurations for moves of the blank tile. I'm going to return these configurations in a puzzle array with board configuration as data. When I run my code below, it only stores the last move for the blank tile in instances where there are multiple moves for the blank tile. I'm not sure how do stop it from overwriting the previous array data.

```
public Puzzle[] getNextPuzzle(Puzzle current) {

    //returns list of indicies representing moves as integers
    int[] ms = current.possibleMoves();
    //trims the previous move so we don't move backwards
    int[] moves = current.removeLastCase(ms);
    //return all possible configurations of puzzles based on moves
    Puzzle[] ret = new Puzzle[moves.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = new Puzzle();
        //set array puzzle configuration to current configuration
        ret[i].setPuzzle(current.getPuzzle());
        //***System.out.Print(current.getPuzzle());
        //returns array index where blank tile is
        int num = ret[i].indexOf(0);
        //swaps the indices passed in: numbered instruction index and blank tile
        ret[i].swap(moves[i], num);
    }
    return ret;
}

Public class Puzzle {
int[] puzzle = new int[9];
public void swap(int locA, int locB) {
    int temp = this.puzzle[locB];
    this.puzzle[locB] = this.puzzle[locA];
    this.puzzle[locA] = temp;
}
public int indexOf(int n) {
    //will be out of bounds
    int ret = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.puzzle.length; i++) {
        if (this.puzzle[i] == n) {
            ret = i;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
}
```

Sample output:

```
//current configuration
1 4 2 
3 0 5 
6 7 8 
//is solvable
true
//indices of possible moves of blank tile
toRemove[0] 1
toRemove[1] 3
toRemove[2] 5
toRemove[3] 7
//indices with previous state removed for disallow of backwards
ret[0] 3
ret[1] 5
ret[2] 7
//this is being printed out where the *** is 
142305678
142035678
142530678
//what is returned in the array at the very end, expected is 3 different configurations
1 4 2 
5 3 7 
6 0 8 

1 4 2 
5 3 7 
6 0 8 

1 4 2 
5 3 7 
6 0 8
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly (in the code, not in words)? is it that `ret` is an array of length 1? what is the length of `moves`? what do the `possibleMoves` and `removeLastCase` methods do?

Comment: `ret[i].indexOf(0);`can you show `indexOf()` in details

Comment: @vefthym `possibleMoves` returns an integer array of the indices of adjacent tiles, and `removeLastCase` takes in an integer array and returns one with length -1 and the last previous board configuration removed from the possible move list (so we can't go to the board we just came from)

Comment: ok, thanks. I know that it may be hard to produce, but can you give us a minimal example execution, what went wrong and what you expected? It will help you get (better) answers.

Comment: @vefthym let me know if you want anything else in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a shallow copy of the current puzzle, so you change the current puzzle in each loop. You should, instead create a deep copy of the current puzzle, and leave the current puzzle intact. I don't know the full implementation of your Puzzle class, but you may want to check your constructor and setter methods.

Create a new constructor for Puzzle:

```
public Puzzle (int[] puzzle) { 
    //this creates a deep copy
    this.puzzle = new int[puzzle.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.length; ++i) {
        this.puzzle[i] = puzzle[i]; 
    }        
}
```

and then replace the following lines:

```
ret[i] = new Puzzle();
//set array puzzle configuration to current configuration
ret[i].setPuzzle(current.getPuzzle());
```

with:

```
ret[i] = new Puzzle(current.getPuzzle());
```

For a nice explanation of deep vs shallow copy, I recommend [this post](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/deepCopying.htm).

Comment: You still get the same, three repeated configurations for output with this.... :/

Comment: @user3413170 sorry for my last edit, I thought Arrays.copyOf was creating a deep copy. Check this please and let me know if it works.

Comment: It's ok, I had to sleep in that time anyways. I have updated my code, and right now it's working. Thank you so much for your help